# Android, creating reference class array

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm slowly getting crazy... trying to define a very simple class array to hold instances of other reference class.
But I'm getting null pointer error all the time.
What do I wrong?
For any help I am very thankful!!

```
//-------------------------
// main activity
//-------------------------
package bangkokguy.android.fromscratch;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Palya kaki = new Palya();
}

@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
//-------------------------
// class Palya
//-------------------------
package bangkokguy.android.fromscratch;

public class Palya {
  public Kocka sok_kocka [];
  public Palya() {
    sok_kocka = new Kocka[10];
    <b>sok_kocka [1].letter = ' '; /*!!! null pointer here */</b>
  }
}
//-------------------------
// class Kocka
//-------------------------
package bangkokguy.android.fromscratch;

public class Kocka /*implements _NewLetter, _IsFree*/ {
  public char letter;
  static final char c_empty = ' ';
  public Kocka () {letter = c_empty;}
  public Kocka (char letterke) {letter = letterke;}
  public void _NewLetter (char letterke) {letter = letterke;}
  public boolean _IsFree () {return letter == c_empty;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the array isn't enough, you also have to give each index something to hold. Otherwise, each index in the array will hold `null` for Object arrays.
For example, to assign something to index 0 after creating the array:

```
sok_kocka = new Kocka[10]; 
sok_kocka [0] = new Kocka();
```

You will have to do this for all the indexes in the array if you want to avoid NPEs. Also keep in mind array indexes *start* at `0`, ***not*** `1`.

Answer (score 0):

`sok_kocka = new Kocka[10];` creates an empty array of size 10 that can hold objects of type "Kocka". This however does not mean that the array has any items in it - You have to assign those manually.